# Is there a way in Ruby to print out the public methods of an Object

Tags: ruby, reflection, public-method

... without including all of the public methods of the generic Object? I mean, other than doing array subtraction. I just want to quickly review what's available to me from an object sometimes without going to the docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`methods`, `instance_methods`, `public_methods`, `private_methods` and `protected_methods` all accept a boolean parameter to determine if the methods of your object's parents are included.

For example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > class MyClass < Object; def my_method; return true; end; end;
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > MyClass.new.public_methods
 => [:my_method, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :to_s, :inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :define_singleton_method, :__id__, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > MyClass.new.public_methods(false)
 => [:my_method]
```

As noted by @Marnen, the methods defined dynamically (eg. with `method_missing`) won't appear here. Your only bet for these ones is hoping that the libraries you're using are well documented.

Comment: Perhaps you should change your example to something like `''.public_methods` or `[].public_methods` instead. It's obvious to anyone who knows Ruby that your example lists the methods that the `Array` class object *itself* responds to and *not* the instance methods of the `Array` class, but it might be misleading to novices.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for the input. I went with a custom class because the Array or String instance have too many methods and the SO code blocks don't wrap lines. It wasn't immediately clear the results weren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you were looking for?

```
class Foo
  def bar
    p "bar"
  end
end

p Foo.public_instance_methods(false) # => [:bar]
```

ps I expect this was not the result you were after:

```
p Foo.public_methods(false)          # => [:allocate, :new, :superclass]
```

Answer (score 0):

I started to try to document all these inspection methods at one point in https://github.com/bf4/Notes/blob/master/code/ruby_inspection.rb

As noted in other answers:

```
class Foo; def bar; end; def self.baz; end; end
```

Firstly, I like to sort the methods

```
Foo.public_methods.sort # all public instance methods
Foo.public_methods(false).sort # public class methods defined in the class
Foo.new.public_methods.sort # all public instance methods
Foo.new.public_methods(false).sort # public instance methods defined in the class
```

Useful tip Grep to find out what your options are

```
Foo.public_methods.sort.grep /methods/ # all public class methods matching /method/
# ["instance_methods", "methods", "private_instance_methods", "private_methods", "protected_instance_methods", "protected_methods", "public_instance_methods", "public_methods", "singleton_methods"]
Foo.new.public_methods.sort.grep /methods/
#  ["methods", "private_methods", "protected_methods", "public_methods", "singleton_methods"]
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick

Answer (score -1):

If there were, it wouldn't be terribly useful: often, the public methods are not your only options, due to Ruby's ability to fake methods by dynamic metaprogramming. So you can't really rely on `instance_methods` to tell you much that's useful.