# ruby: how to get all the methods that are defined or overwrited in current class rather than base class?

Tags: ruby, reflection

Does anyone how to get all the methods that are defined or overwrited in current class rather than base class?
e.g.

```
class MyBase
  def Test
  end
end

class MyDerived
  def Test1
  end
end
```

When I call MyDerived.methods, i got a lot of methods, but I only want to get 'Test1' because it is its own method, is it possible?
thanks.

Comment: Something like `.instance_methods(false)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end
end

Foo.new.public_methods false

=> [:bar]
```

Comment: You can also call Foo.new.method(:bar) to see where the method :bar was defined.  You can also take advantage of how ruby subtracts arrays to, for example, see the methods added since a particular ancestors, e.g. Foo.new.public_methods(false) - Object.new.public_methods(false), or something like Foo.public_methods - (Foo.ancestors - Foo.included_modules)[1].public_methods see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138304/is-there-a-way-in-ruby-to-print-out-the-public-methods-of-an-object/8156584#8156584